# My object renders from a weird place

Tags: rendering

So, I made a street sign with using textures. When I try to render, it shows the inside of the pole. I try to change the view but i can not. How can I change the render view and why does it happen?

Thank you.

[image: what is looks like from the viewport]

[image: how it renders]

[image: how it looks after i try to change the render view by " ctrl + alt + numpad0]

Comment: I tried to change it by ctrl + alt + numpad 0 but the object disfigures after i try to do that.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: use the link I've just given, you need to copy paste the URL of this page, then copy paste here the link it will give

Comment: Hey, i actually tried a way and solved it. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had many objects in my scene and i realized that i had another camera in the deep of the object. I searched  " camera " in hiearchy and found it.